# I want to use reactive function in a R shiny app, but getting stuck in between

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am providing below the R code for shiny app where I am getting problem:

```
Planning_data_Selected_filtered <- reactive({
subset(Planning_data_Selected , Planning_data_Selected$Cost_Element %in% input$Cost_Element & Planning_data_Selected$Cost_Center %in% input$Cost_Center)
})

Planning_data_Selected_new <- Planning_data_Selected_filtered()
Planning_data_Selected_new$Planning_Cost <- round(as.numeric(na_to_zero(Planning_data_Selected_new$Planning_Cost)), 0)
Planning_data_Selected_new$Planning_Cost_Revised <- round(as.numeric(Planning_data_Selected_new$Planning_Cost), 0)
Planning_data_Selected_new$Row_ID <- as.numeric(Planning_data_Selected_new$Row_ID)

Planning_data_Selected_disp <- Planning_data_Selected_new %>%
select(-c(RF1, Document_Date, Created_on, Document_Header_Text, Entered_by, Exchange_Rate_Type, `Fiscal _Year`)) %>% 
rename(Fiscal_Year = Fiscal_Year1)
```

please note that Planning_data_Selected has been calculated previously. I need to filter it everytime when I get the inputs - cost center and cost elements. Depending f these 2 inputs, I need my data to have its proper subset. and then I am calculating few things on the same data(subset) and then displayin gthe same on shiny page.

I am using reactive () for first time. Please help.

Comment: What kind of "problem" are you getting? Do you have any erro msg, etc? Where is your `reactive()` used? Is it inside render(), etc?

Comment: hi, can you add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example? It will be much easier to help you with that